# Display:inline-block on table elements is inconsistent between browsers

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a comment field and I want to expand if the user wants more lines to write comments.

I can have up to 4 supported lines.

All 4 lines are part of a form which is fine because they can be blank.

I have the code as below:

```js
  $('#addcomment').click(function(){
        $('.hiddenComment').css("display", "inline-block");
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<tr>
       <td class="formtitle">Comments</td>
       <td class="formfield"><input id="inputdesc" name="comments" type="text" size="70" maxlength="60" /><span id="charcount" style="display:none; padding-left:10px; padding-right: 10px; color:#B5B5B5; width: 10px;">60</span><img id="addcomment" style="vertical-align: text-bottom" src="/files/icons/label.png" /></td>
      </tr>
      <tr class="hiddenComment" id="comment2" style="display: none">
       <td class="formtitle">Comments 2</td>
       <td class="formfield"><input id="inputdesc" name="comments2" type="text" size="70" maxlength="40" /><span id="charcount" style="display:none; padding-left:10px; padding-right: 10px; color:#B5B5B5; width: 10px;">60</span></td>
      </tr>
      <tr class="hiddenComment" id="comment3" style="display: none">
       <td class="formtitle">Comments 3</td>
       <td class="formfield"><input id="inputdesc" name="comments2" type="text" size="70" maxlength="40" /><span id="charcount" style="display:none; padding-left:10px; padding-right: 10px; color:#B5B5B5; width: 10px;">60</span></td>
      </tr>
      <tr class="hiddenComment" id="comment4" style="display: none">
       <td class="formtitle">Comments 4</td>
       <td class="formfield"><input id="inputdesc" name="comments2" type="text" size="70" maxlength="40" /><span id="charcount" style="display:none; padding-left:10px; padding-right: 10px; color:#B5B5B5; width: 10px;">60</span></td>
      </tr>
```

So when the button is clicked, it should display the extra rows.

**It works in IE**.. Surprisingly..
[image]

However is **doesn't seem to work in Chrome**. It weirdly spews the rows out of line with the others:
[image]

Does anyone have any ideas at to why Chrome displays the tables this way?

Thanks

Comment: Have you tried `display: inline-table`?

Comment: i think that inline-block remove your "tr" , try to use only div's instead of a table.

Comment: @zer00ne Yeah I've tried that, same thing :\

Comment: @IlyasMimouni It's a legacy application which is built using tables, not my call to change it unfortunately..

Comment: Since they're table rows, have you tried `$('.hiddenComment').css("display", "table-row");`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use the jquery functions `'.show()'` and `'.hide()'`

I also added width="120" to fix width of the column but not very necessary.

```js
$('.formtitle, .formfield').hide();
$('.base, .hiddenComment').show();

  $('#addcomment').click(function(){
        $('.formtitle, .formfield').show();
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
   <tr>
       <td class="formtitle base" width="120">Comments</td>
       <td class="formfield base"><input id="inputdesc" name="comments" type="text" size="70" maxlength="60" /><span id="charcount" style="display:none; padding-left:10px; padding-right: 10px; color:#B5B5B5; width: 10px;">60</span><img id="addcomment" style="vertical-align: text-bottom" src="/files/icons/label.png" /></td>
      </tr>
      <tr class="hiddenComment" id="comment2" style="display: none">
       <td class="formtitle">Comments 2</td>
       <td class="formfield"><input id="inputdesc" name="comments2" type="text" size="70" maxlength="40" /><span id="charcount" style="display:none; padding-left:10px; padding-right: 10px; color:#B5B5B5; width: 10px;">60</span></td>
      </tr>
      <tr class="hiddenComment" id="comment3" style="display: none">
       <td class="formtitle">Comments 3</td>
       <td class="formfield"><input id="inputdesc" name="comments2" type="text" size="70" maxlength="40" /><span id="charcount" style="display:none; padding-left:10px; padding-right: 10px; color:#B5B5B5; width: 10px;">60</span></td>
      </tr>
      <tr class="hiddenComment" id="comment4" style="display: none">
       <td class="formtitle">Comments 4</td>
       <td class="formfield"><input id="inputdesc" name="comments2" type="text" size="70" maxlength="40" /><span id="charcount" style="display:none; padding-left:10px; padding-right: 10px; color:#B5B5B5; width: 10px;">60</span></td>
      </tr>
   
</table>
```

---

## Solution 2 :

and you can try this code for show and hide on click :

```
<script>
$('.formtitle, .formfield').hide();
$('.base, .hiddenComment').show();

var view=false;
$('#addcomment').click(function(){
    view = !view;
    if(view){
       $('.formtitle, .formfield').show();
    }
    else{
        $('.formtitle, .formfield').hide();
        $('.base, .hiddenComment').show();
    }
});
</script>
```

---

## Solution 3 :

```
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <table>
                <tr>
                    <td class="formtitle" width="120">Comments</td>
                    <td class="formfield"><input id="inputdesc" name="comments" type="text" size="70" maxlength="60" /><span id="charcount" style="display:none; padding-left:10px; padding-right: 10px; color:#B5B5B5; width: 10px;">60</span><img id="addcomment" style="vertical-align: text-bottom" src="/files/icons/label.png" /></td>
                </tr>
                <tr class="hiddenComment" id="comment2" style="display: none">
                    <td class="formtitle">Comments 2</td>
                    <td class="formfield"><input id="inputdesc" name="comments2" type="text" size="70" maxlength="40" /><span id="charcount" style="display:none; padding-left:10px; padding-right: 10px; color:#B5B5B5; width: 10px;">60</span></td>
                </tr>
                <tr class="hiddenComment" id="comment3" style="display: none">
                    <td class="formtitle">Comments 3</td>
                    <td class="formfield"><input id="inputdesc" name="comments2" type="text" size="70" maxlength="40" /><span id="charcount" style="display:none; padding-left:10px; padding-right: 10px; color:#B5B5B5; width: 10px;">60</span></td>
                </tr>
                <tr class="hiddenComment" id="comment4" style="display: none">
                    <td class="formtitle">Comments 4</td>
                    <td class="formfield"><input id="inputdesc" name="comments2" type="text" size="70" maxlength="40" /><span id="charcount" style="display:none; padding-left:10px; padding-right: 10px; color:#B5B5B5; width: 10px;">60</span></td>
                </tr>

    </table>    

<script>
 $('.hiddenComment').show();
 $('.hiddenComment > td').hide();

        var view=false;
        $('#addcomment').click(function(){
            view = !view;

            if(view){
               $('.hiddenComment > td').show();
            }
            else{
                $('.hiddenComment > td').hide();
            }
        });
</script>
```

Comment: Thankyou Ilyas, works perfectly - cross browser. With the added benefit of showing the tables if javascript isn't turned on.